# Artefact in World background

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, world

I'm making a space World with shader nodes. Here's a simplified version with only black background and the Sun. The Sun location is set by an object:

[image: Shader nodes for World]

This is how the Sun looks:

[image: White Sun with black bkgd]

However, in the opposite direction, there's a small artefact:

[image: Artefact]

How to get rid of the artefact?

Edit. I'm using Eevee.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Allright I figured it out. All I had to do is to clamp that arccosine argument.

[image: shader nodes]